# Android ListView w/ multiple Layouts: why bother with `getItemViewType` at all?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

The recommended approach to populating an Android `ListView` with different layouts seems to be to override

- `getItemViewType(int position)`, and
- `getViewTypeCount()`.

This is made clear in many questions and answers here (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layouts-for-each-row), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467455/android-listview-with-multiple-layouts) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723277/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row)).

When looking at the concrete code samples/tutorials, however, I can't really see why overriding these methods is the correct approach:

- Basically the entire process still boils down to having some sort of **conditional/switch** statement int `getView(...)` that inflates the correct layout depending on the list item at the given position.
- This conditional/switch has to be written **manually** it seems - so why bother with overriding the above methods at all, if you're going to simply inflate hand-picked layouts anyway?

The main issue is see is that using the `getItemViewType` signature forces you to first encode your layout types to an `int` and then (in `getView(...)` decoding this int again to any layout type... This adds additional complexity and potential for errors.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `ListView` is basically replaced by `RecyclerView` now.
By the way the reason seems to be that the inflate code is done for you based on the ViewType you return in `getItemViewType`. I think it has to do with the Recycling logic of the views as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300962/getviewtypecount-and-getitemviewtype-methods-of-arrayadapter). The framework calls `getItemViewType`, using it to determine if it can return a recycled view or if it has to call `getView` to inflate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, I have used ListView with several layouts without overriding `getItemViewType()` and just putting conditionals in `getView()`,

Later I did transition to RecyclerView and then `getItemViewType()` makes really sense because the type returned is what marks what view is recycled and which one does not.

For me RecyclerView is much better, Have you thought about switching to RecyclerView?

Answer (score 0):

Even for `ListView`, `getItemViewType()` is necessary if you want to have more than one kind of layout in your adapter.

You are correct that `getView()` will still have to be modified to work with the right type of view, but correctly implementing `getItemViewType()` is what makes sure that the `convertView` argument passed to `getView()` is of the right structure. If you don't override `getItemViewType()`, you are defeating the view recycling that makes `ListView` performant.